# How to call SignalR hub method from react?

Tags: c#, reactjs, azure-functions, signalr

I'm trying to call the JoinUserToGroup method from a react project, but I'm not getting any response/result. I have implemented SignalR in an Azure Function. NOTE: the negotiate method is being called properly. Please check my code:

SignalRTest.cs

```
public class SignalRTest : ServerlessHub
{
    private const string NewMessageTarget = "newMessage";
    private const string NewConnectionTarget = "newConnection";

    [FunctionName("index")]
    public IActionResult GetHomePage([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "content", "index.html");
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = File.ReadAllText(path),
            ContentType = "text/html",
        };
    }

    [FunctionName("negotiate")]
    public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req, 
        [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "serverless")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        return connectionInfo;
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(OnConnected))]
    public async Task OnConnected([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, ILogger logger)
    {
        invocationContext.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var auth);
        await Clients.All.SendAsync(NewConnectionTarget, new NewConnection(invocationContext.ConnectionId, auth));
        logger.LogInformation($"{invocationContext.ConnectionId} has connected");
    }


    [FunctionName(nameof(Broadcast))]
    public async Task Broadcast([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string message, ILogger logger)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync(NewMessageTarget, new NewMessage(invocationContext, message));
        logger.LogInformation($"{invocationContext.ConnectionId} broadcast {message}");
    }


    [FunctionName(nameof(SendMessageToTarget))]
    public async Task SendMessageToTarget(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req,
        [SignalR(HubName = "serverless")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages)

    {

        var requestBody = req.Body.ToString();
        var clientMessage = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

        await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
            new SignalRMessage
            {
                Target = (string)clientMessage["Target"],
                Arguments = new[] { (string)clientMessage["Message"] }
            });
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(SendToGroup))]
    public async Task SendToGroup([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string groupName, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync(NewMessageTarget, new NewMessage(invocationContext, message));
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(SendToUser))]
    public async Task SendToUser([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string userName, string message)
    {
        await Clients.User(userName).SendAsync(NewMessageTarget, new NewMessage(invocationContext, message));
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(SendToConnection))]
    public async Task SendToConnection([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string connectionId, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync(NewMessageTarget, new NewMessage(invocationContext, message));
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(JoinGroup))]
    public async Task JoinGroup([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string connectionId, string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionId, groupName);
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(LeaveGroup))]
    public async Task LeaveGroup([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string connectionId, string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(connectionId, groupName);
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(JoinUserToGroup))]
    public async Task JoinUserToGroup([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string userName, string groupName)
    {
        await UserGroups.AddToGroupAsync(userName, groupName);
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(LeaveUserFromGroup))]
    public async Task LeaveUserFromGroup([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string userName, string groupName)
    {
        await UserGroups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(userName, groupName);
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(OnDisconnected))]
    public void OnDisconnected([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext)
    {
    }

    private class NewConnection
    {
        public string ConnectionId { get; }

        public string Authentication { get; }

        public NewConnection(string connectionId, string authentication)
        {
            ConnectionId = connectionId;
            Authentication = authentication;
        }
    }

    private class NewMessage
    {
        public string ConnectionId { get; }
        public string Sender { get; }
        public string Text { get; }

        public NewMessage(InvocationContext invocationContext, string message)
        {
            Sender = string.IsNullOrEmpty(invocationContext.UserId) ? string.Empty : invocationContext.UserId;
            ConnectionId = invocationContext.ConnectionId;
            Text = message;
        }
    }
}
```

My react code:

```
const createSignalRConnection = async () => {
    let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://localhost:7004/api", {withCredentials: false})
    .build();

    await connection.start().catch(err => alert(err));

    connection.invoke("joinUserToGroup", loggedUser, currentChatId).then((x: any) => {
        console.log("User joined to SignalR group");
    })
    .catch(err => alert(err));
};

useEffect(() => {
    createSignalRConnection();
}, [currentChatId]);
```

More info:
I'm using NET 6. The SignalR package in Azure Function project is: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService.
The SignalR package in the React project is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr?activeTab=readme

Azure function project running:
[image]

I marked a breakpoint at JoinUserToGroup method, but it's not being hit. Please let me know if I'm calling the JoinUserToGroup using a wrong approach. Thanks!.

Comment: You need to provide to us some more information, like what is `endpoints.MapHub<SignalRTest>("/xxx")`? DotNetCore version? SignalR NPM package name?

Comment: @scccboom I just edited my question including more details. Thanks!.

Comment: I found an [example](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/blob/main/samples/BidirectionChat/csharp/content/index.html) of Vue. In code `connection` is global, and print status in callback `console.log(‘connected!’)`,`console.log('disconnected')` try it.